# how to filter jmeter dashboard that generated using maven project

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am generating a dashboard using jmeter, and I want to restrict warmup requests like (sampler names) `setPost`, `setGet`, `setPut`, and `setDelete` from showing up in the dashboard. But, these have to be run before running other requests.

I tried to use:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=[^setPost]|[^setGet]|[^setPut]|[^setDelete]
```

in the `reportgenerator.properties` file, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JMeter use Menu

- Help > Export Transactions for report

[image: Help menu]

Remove what you don't want.

Finally copy this to user.properties, read [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) for more details.

For maven, see [this](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#2) so set in pom.xml :

```
  <configuration>
     <propertiesJMeter>
        <jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter>^(Java Request)(-success|-failure)?$</jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter>
     </propertiesJMeter>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: can you give me a link how to filter dashboard

Comment: thank you, but is there is any way to ignore requests with name above I mentioned instead of writing all request names I have more than 20 request with different names, but request names are different for each test plan only common is request which I have mentioned in question

Comment: Try this ^(?!IgnoreMe)(-success|-failure)?$

Comment: is there any chance to ignore all requests in a thread for the first loop, if I have 1 thread and 11 loops ignore results of 1st loop in the report